# HDD works when plugged in via USB SATA, but not internal SATA?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, sata

I have a client's laptop HDD that will boot (slowly) to Windows 10 if plugged in with my USB to SATA adapter connector, but won't boot if plugged directly into the standard on-board hard drive bay of the Dell laptop (via SATA I assume). When it doesn't boot, it shows just a black screen with a blinking cursor upper left after the boot menu.  I know the internal SATA connection is working because it will boot as expected with the original HDD with Windows that was installed on the Dell prior.

Could this be due to a mismatch in the Windows key? The Dell laptop has Windows 7 installed and the hard drive has Windows 10.
Not sure where to go from this blinking cursor, but any ideas help!

Notes:

- Booting with UEFI displays `No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics.`, so I am booting Legacy... I thought UEFI was standard now?
- AHCI Booting enabled

Comment: Did the drive previously boot in that laptop? Some drives (shucked from external/portable HDDs) will refuse to start if 3.3V is connected, which USB <=> SATA may not provide. Might be worth taping over the 3.3V contacts on the power connector as an experiment.

Comment: @bob no, the drive has never booted from this Dell laptop. Pulled from another laptop with a broken screen, so the client doesn't have to pay $200+ to reinstall this eGenuity PoS. 

I tried to tape off the power connector when inserting internally to drive bay and the blinking cursor disappeared, and instead showed "no boot device found" screen. Is that what you were thinkin?

Comment: Does the disk have an 'EFI system partition'? Is it recognized by a Linux live-CD when it's directly SATA-connected? Does Linux `fdisk -l` report identical partitions, and identical "Sector size", for both SATA and USB connections?

Comment: @DangerDoug Did you tape off only the 3.3V parts (leaving 5V/12V) or the entire connector?

Comment: @grawity booting with UEFI in bios of laptop causes bootable devices to not be detected, thats EFI correct? I will need to create a linux live cd, looks useful in troubleshooting this sort of thing! will report back on that.

Comment: @grawity booting with UEFI in bios of laptop causes bootable devices to not be detected, thats EFI correct? I will need to create a linux live cd, looks useful in troubleshooting this sort of thing! will report back on that.

Comment: @bob I electrical taped off the whole power connector *face palm*, I have a diagram here I am gunna follow and try and just tape off those connectors.